# configuring django with nginx gunicorn on docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx

Good day, I am new to docker and I have a Django app I will like to dockerize, I have searched for tutorials to help me set up my Django app with docker, I followed this article here on test-driven https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/. I get issues making nginx work with my app. here is my code.

my apps docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

ENV PATH="/scripts:${PATH}"

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt


RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./testdocker /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./scripts /scripts

RUN chmod +x /scripts/*

RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/media
RUN mkdir -p /vol/web/static

RUN adduser -D user
RUN chown -R user:user /vol

RUN chmod -R 755 /vol/web

USER user

nginx docker file:

FROM nginx:1.19.3-alpine

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d

RUN mkdir -p /vol/static

my docker-compose file:

version: '3.7'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        command: sh -c "gunicorn testdocker.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
        volumes:
            - static_data:/vol/web
        expose:
            - "8000"
        environment: 
            - SECRET_KEY=MANME1233
            - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1, localhost
    
    nginx:
        build: 
            context: ./nginx
        volumes: 
            - static_data:/vol/static
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        depends_on:
            - app

volumes: 
    static_data:


my nginx conf file:

 upstream testapp {
     server app:8000;
 }

    server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name app;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://testapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
  
    location /static {
        alias /vol/static;
    }

}
```

I can't seem to get nginx to reverse proxy to my web app, upon opening the URL on the browser I get a 404 bad request or address not found. please what am I doing wrong or not doing right?.

Answer (score 1):

@victormazeli It looks like you missed placing your services within the same docker network and I see some misconfiguration in `nginx` conf file. Try updating your `docker-compose.yml` as follows:

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
    app:
        build:
            context: .
        command: sh -c "gunicorn testdocker.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
        volumes:
            - static_data:/vol/web
        expose:
            - "8000"
        environment: 
            - SECRET_KEY=MANME1233
            - ALLOWED_HOSTS=127.0.0.1, localhost
        networks:
            - main
    
    nginx:
        build: 
            context: ./nginx
        volumes: 
            - static_data:/vol/static
        ports: 
            - "8080:80"
        depends_on:
            - app
        networks:
            - main

volumes: 
    static_data:
networks:
    main:
```

Then, update your `nginx` config as follows:

```
server {
  server_name nginx;
  listen 80;

  location /static {
    alias /vol/static;
  }
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app:8000/;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }

}
```

Another thing to keep in mind here is that you have 2 targets that are being served by the NGINX reverse-proxy:

1. Django project located in `testdocker` which should be accessible via `localhost:8080`
2. Static file data which is accessible via `localhost:8080/static/[relative_path]`

To access the static data, you will need the path relative to `/vol/static` in `nginx` service (which is a docker volume mount also mounted to `/vol/web` in `app` service). According to `app`'s `Dockerfile`, the `static_data` volume should contain 2 directories: `media` and `static`. Therefore, if you have say an `index.html` located in directory `/vol/web/static` in `app` service, it should be accessible via `localhost:8080/static/static/index.html`.

Give this a try and let me know how it works out for you.

Comment: hi Rapheal i tried your solution and i still get same error "BAD REQUEST", and also when i type the localhost adress as so: 127.0.0.1:8080 i get a blank static page, and my web app still does not run @ 127.0.0.1:8000 or localhost:8000, all returns a "BAD REQUEST".

Comment: Can you share what is in your `Dockerfiles`? Where is the actual static content that you are trying to serve stored? As shared, looks like you are using a docker volume, have you intentionally saved it there and verified it has actual content there? To verify, run `docker exec [name_of_nginx_container] ls -la /vol/static`. If it doesn't print anything, it is empty. Let me know and I can update the answer based on the result.

Comment: Hi Rapheal when i execute the above command it does print out info of files stored in vol/static. As for my docker files there all presented above.

Comment: @victormazeli It should work perhaps you are not checking the right endpoints? Regarding the "BAD REQUEST" mentioned, since you [expose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#expose) in your `docker-compose.yml` it is only available to 'linked' docker services internally. To publish to the host so you can properly resolve `localhost:8000`, you will need to modify it to `ports` configuration similarly as in `nginx` services. You will need to set an element into the `ports` key as `"8000:8000"` for `app` service.

Comment: @victormazeli Once the above is done, you can verify if the result of `localhost:8000` and `localhost:8080` match. If they do, then NGINX is configured correctly. If it is a blank page and that is not what was intended, then there may be a problem with your Django project (I've tested using [hello_django](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) and it worked fine).

Comment: @victormazeli Regarding access to the static file content, I have added a note at the end of my answer that might clear up some possible confusion. If you find that it helps you resolve your issue, I'd appreciate your acceptance of the answer.